# Ingesting json dump in AWS RDS

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I made a django application and want to use an sqlite3 db for local development and a Amazon MySql RDS DB for production. My webserver is running on an EC2 Instance.

I have exported the data from the sqlite3 db to a json object using `python manage.py dumpdata > datadump.json` 
Is there a way to import this JSON into a MySql DB in RDS or should I tackle this problem in a different manner?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have your data in that local .json file and you don't want to mess around with porting it into your EC2 instance to load it, you can connect to your RDS locally by grabbing the same connection settings your EC2 instance is using (changing the `DATABASES` in settings.py).

Once you point your local deploy to your cloud database, you can then run `python manage.py loaddata datadump.json` to read that data in. Make sure to migrate the database first so it's working off of the same table structures.

Side note: instead of dumping everything, you might want to just target your specific app, and maybe your user tables. So instead of running `python manage.py dumpdata > datadump.json` switching the database then running `python manage.py loaddata datadump.json`, you could do this instead:

```
python manage.py dumpdata auth.user > user.json
python manage.py dumpdata myapp > datadump.json
```

Switch over to your cloud DB, then:

```
python manage.py loaddata user.json
python manage.py loaddata datadump.json
```

If you don't select the specific app you want to dump, I've found that you can run into uniqueness issues with the data that Django gives you out of the box.